# how to change the fps of video during playback of video without restarting video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I want to change the fps of video at run time (during the playback of video) without restarting or pausing using ffmpeg. I searched about it in the internet but I am not able to get the command which can change the fps directly without restarting the video but i found ffmpeg command which can create a new file with modified fps as shown below.
**ffmpeg -y -r 20 -i input_file -r 45 output_file**
Is it possible to change fps of video during run time using ffmpeg command ? If yes please provide me the command if not how can i change using c code. Please help me in this issue as early as possible. 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to simply not display all the frames on the client playback side, or do you mean you want to change the streamed fps at the server/headend side?

Comment: @Mick yes I want to change the streamed fps without restarting or pausing the video. For example, if I am playing some video in vlc and from terminal if I apply command to change the fps of streamed video, the fps of streamed video should change without restarting or creating new output file with modified fps. Is there any command using ffmpeg with which I can change streamed fps or with the help of C program ?